# Is there any way for me to turn off just the music in The Binding of Isaac?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

I've got nothing against the awesome soundtrack of The Binding of Isaac, but I love to blast other songs while I play video games, so I'm trying to turn the music off. There doesn't seem to be any option from the main menu, however, and there's no config file for the game as far as I can tell. Is it still possible to turn off the music?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Press "M" to toggle music during the game.

Answer (score 7):

Click "options".

[image]

Comment: Oh! Oh. There...there is an options menu. Oh.